# How to fix indentation in Systemverilog source

Tags: indentation, system-verilog, auto-indent, ultraedit

I am using systemverilog very often.
I am using **UltraEdit** as text editor. I use also VIM.
Sometimes I have to copy code from some other places and paste it into my code.
It may not be indented properly. It is a difficult task to indent it properly again.

Can anybody suggest any method or tool to do it easily?

Answer (score 9):

#### Method

1. Visit [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/)
2. Paste your code into one of the editor windows
3. Select all text with `CTRL-A`
4. Reindent all text with `SHIFT-TAB`

#### Some backgroud

There is a Verilog mode for [Code Mirror](http://codemirror.net/) which supports SystemVerilog. [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) is an in-browser text editor written in JavaScript which is used on a number of websites, including [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/).

You could also paste and reindent in the [example window here](http://codemirror.net/mode/verilog/index.html), or you could download it yourself and run it locally.

Answer (score 2):

The verilog mode in Emacs supports indentation, so you can open your file in Emacs (from the command line, run `emacs file-name.v`, select all by pressing `Ctrl+H`, then reindent by pressing `TAB` and save with `Ctrl+S`.

Answer (score 0):

UltraEdit has command **ReIndent Selection** at bottom of menu **Format**.

All lines of a selection of any type of text file can be re-indented (not reformatted, i.e. not inserting line breaks or removing line breaks) with this command as long as

1. the file is syntax highlighted based on a wordfile (*.uew) suitable for type of text file,
2. the syntax highlighting wordfile contains appropriate indent/unindent string definitions.

Therefore it is no problem to re-indent code after paste by selecting pasted block and use the command **ReIndent Selection** with a good syntax highlighting wordfile for **SystemVerilog**.

The syntax highlighting wordfile currently used for active file can be opened for editing or improvement by clicking on button **Open** left of language list box preselected according to used syntax highlighting for active file at **Advanced - Setttings** or **Configuration - Editor Display - Syntax Highlighting**.

The lines of interest in the wordfile regarding indent/unindent start with

```
/Indent Strings =
/Unindent Strings =
/Ignore Strings SOL =
```

More information about those three lines can be found

- in help of UltraEdit on page **Syntax Highlighting**,
- in online help on page about [wordfiles](https://www.ultraedit.com/wiki/Wordfiles), and
- in user forum topic [template for syntax highlighting language wordfile](http://forums.ultraedit.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4124).

A user contributed syntax highlighting wordfile for **SystemVerilog** can be downloaded from [wordfiles](https://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/extras/wordfiles.html) page.

Note: As command **ReIndent Selection** is a basic command for all languages, it is not as smart as tools written to re-indent or even reformat source files written for specific languages with true language intellisense like [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) for C / C++ / C# and Java (also supported built-in by UE).